# How to locate the real file with exception

Tags: nestjs

When my app is crashed, nestjs handled a exception, but i cannot get the real problem file

Exception Stack:

```
[Nest] 17946   - 4/18/2018, 5:00:56 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_app_name"
QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_app_name"
    at new QueryFailedError (.../src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:7:9)
    at Query.<anonymous> (.../src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:216:26)
    at Query.handleError (.../node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:143:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (.../node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Connection.emit (domain.js:422:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
```

the `...` is my work dir

**how do i know which file the exception from**

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown in `PostgresQueryRunner.js`, which is, not **your** codebase.
Your app tried to insert a duplicate value in a table column indexed as `unique`, in your PgSQL database.

Comment: yep, but I want to record in the log where this operation is done